# Sharing common session/cache between django/python and java/play

Tags: java, django, session, serialization, memcached

My application has setup of nginx - uwsgi - django - python stack on one ec2 machine A.

What I want to do is to have parallel development for some pages using java/play framework on a different ec2 machine B.

nginx on machine A will redirect some urls to machine B, this is working fine.

I have problem with maintaining user sessions, rather I don't know how can I do that. What I want to do is that java/play on machine A know if a user has be logged in on ec2 machine B and vice versa.

Can I use memcached in some way or cookies, I don't know . Please suggest.

Comment: Sessions are at a machine level. Cookies would be a good choice if its on the same domain, or sub domain cross access. I would pass a parameter to your new box something like ?token=ajkdfkjadf etc. With that look up in the database and grab the data you need and restart the session manual then burn that token so it can't be used again.

Comment: I guess the same. I think that I need to set a cookie at authentication happening at either side.  but what should be that cookie so that some one cannot fake other user login.

Comment: There is table django_session that contains session_key and session_data . Can I somehow get session_data deserialized on java side ? I think this can solve my issue w/o adding any memcache layer. I have same db backend on the both.